# Who can see the "past names" field in user profiles?

Tags: support, profile-page, display-names

There's a new numerical field in user profiles called "past names" which when clicked will display a dialog listing previous usernames and when they were last used. *(I can only see this on my own profile, but I assume others have it on their profile pages as well.)*

Who can see other users' past names? Is it only moderators?

Comment: These are [your past lives](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Avatar).

Comment: Does one get option to delete his/her past names if he/she wishes to do so?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Who can see other users' past names? Is it only moderators?

I don't see this on your profile on SO or MSO where I'm a regular user, but I can see it for a different user on [Gardening & Landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/), where I'm a moderator. So your guess is correct: only moderators & devs can view this info.

Here's a screenshot, thanks to [Jeremy Banks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/134300/jeremy-banks):

[image]

Comment: +1 I can see your past names on meta and SO, but not anywhere else.

Comment: True; check for yourself on profiles of users on the [list of well-known name changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/26518#26518).

Comment: Care to give a screenshot? I'm curious.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Just change your name and see it for yourself :) It appears the same way to mods.

Comment: @yoda Oh, I didn't realize. Neat-o, I've been waiting for something like this to be implemented. *edit: [screenshot for the curious](http://i.stack.imgur.com/i2lXQ.png)*

Comment: @JeremyBanks Thanks for the screenshot; I've included it in the answer :)

Comment: As an aside: the list [will be limited to 90 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116870/one-of-my-names-is-missing/116960#116960).

Comment: So that's how StackExchange looked like in 2011.