# One of my names is missing!

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, display-names

Off of discussions from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116794/155556) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116801/155556)

I went to go see it for myself on my meta profile. So i saw that it said I had `4 past names`

I clicked on it an my username `Neal` is not there:
[image: where rrrrrr u?]

That is weird since `Neal` is on my Flair:

[image: profile for amanaP lanaC A nalP A naM A on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

And was pushed to all my accounts at some point.

Was there something I did wrong?

Comment: There isn't a big reason to create an entirely separate tag to distinguish usernames of the past from other username inquiries.

Comment: @GraceNote huh? I have no idea what that means...

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA I think that's regarding you adding [past-names] tag to posts.

Comment: @AnnaLear ahhhh ok. sorry X_x

Comment: I'll look at this tomorrow; I'm busy causing unplanned downtime at the moment ;p

Comment: @Marc arrgh, I didn't think you were meaning that *this* literally! You owe me one great, witty comment. I also accept reimbursement in Euros

Answer (score 7, accepted):

k; in the next build this:

- doesn't miss any names for silly reasons
- doesn't look quite as ugly
- is limited to *recent* names, where "recent" currently means "90 days" - which should be plenty to avoid confusion between users in most cases

Comment: +1 for limiting to 90 days. Very nice!

Comment: Aww, why limit to 90 days? Seeing as it's not public?

Comment: @TheP.G.RepMiningCo. because after a few months it ceases to be quite as confusing.

Comment: And, @The​Pekka, I wonder *why* a moderator needs to see my very old names. (In my case my first name is my full name, which right now they can see in the "real name" field anyhow. But others might have different feelings about that, while I don't see *the need* to reveal that so easily. But it's public indeed, like available in old data dumps.)

Comment: @Arjan 2 main reasons; a: comment chains get disrupted, and sometimes you want to figure out if "Fred" is the "FF" mentioned in a comment, and b: esp. with moderation, it is not uncommon for "trouble" to change names more than most - understanding prior context can be important

Comment: Sure, Marc, but for that the 90 days you're proposing seems quite adequate, doesn't it? (He, @The​Pekka, *it is not uncommon for "trouble" to [change names more than most](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/26518#26518)* `;-)`)

Comment: @Arjan ah, I misread your comment. I think we agree, roughly.

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm this for `Pekka's trolling account`, which isn't there (While `Pekka's other trolling account` is.)

Comment: Yeah, looks like the first name is left off of the list. [This guy wasn't always dripping syrup](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles)

Comment: @Nine yeah - but in my case it wasn't the first name, it was one from the middle of the list.

Comment: Looks like when you copy your profile it has the same effect as initial creation - no rename record.

Comment: @Nine that could be it!

Comment: @probablyPekka - Perhaps "perhaps Pekka" is probably there.