# I want to remove "recent names" from my profile page?

Tags: support, profile-page, display-names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who can see the “past names” field in user profiles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116793/who-can-see-the-past-names-field-in-user-profiles)

I want to remove `recent names` from my profile page?

Answer (score 8):

No need. The only people who can see it are moderators and yourself.

Comment: ok, buy why not give us an option to delete it?

Comment: Why, @darkcrow?

Comment: Worth noting, @darkcrow, that they're "deleted" automatically [after 90 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116870/one-of-my-names-is-missing/116960#116960). Which isn't to say no one on The Internet will remember; The Internet can have a long memory in some cases... FWIW: I *would* like to make this list public, [for 30 days after the change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116801/make-the-past-names-list-public-info-for-30-days-after-changing-your-name) - changing your name can be confusing.

Comment: @Shog9 Ok, making the list public for 30 days seems reasonable, we may also think of keeping the list forever but at the same time we should give the person behind the name option of deleting it if he/she desires so. On Stackoverflow people don't know anyone by name neither is the quality of answer/question is judged by the name of the person.