# Why doesn't the "recent names" field appear for the users who changed their usernames?

Tags: support, profile-page, user-accounts

On *Drupal Answers*, where I am moderator, I noticed that the "recent names" field doesn't appear anymore in the user profiles. For example, it doesn't appear for [this user, who changed his username two times](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/334/pol-dellaiera); it doesn't appear for [this user, who changed his username once](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/1625/letharion).

[image: screenshot]

Does the "recent names" field appear only when the username has been changed X times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's limited to changes [within the past 90 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116870/one-of-my-names-is-missing/116960#116960).

Comment: Oh, Low Quality flag, shining there in the dark where none can see...

Comment: Poor Low Quality flag who cannot be seen in his shiny light. `;)`

Comment: Funny, it keeps coming up in my list even though I flagged it as invalid.