# How long are recent names supposed to be visible?

Tags: support, profile-page, display-names

I have an old display name on StackOverflow from when I merged two accounts a few months back (user1131435). I glanced at my profile today for the first time in a while, and found, to my surprise, that this "recent" name was still listed under `recent names`.

[image: Here is me in a box.]

How long are recent names supposed to remain visible? I thought they were supposed to be there only 30 days.

Comment: Why would it be a problem if they were visible for longer? How does this count as a "bug"? You know that, [so far](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116801/make-the-past-names-list-public-info-for-30-days-after-changing-your-name?rq=1), [only moderators and you can see this info](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116793/who-can-see-the-past-names-field-in-user-profiles), right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The recent names remain visible for [90 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116960/187824).

Comment: If only I had waited three days before asking. Then I wouldn't have needed to ask!