# How many times can I change my profile name?

Tags: support, display-names

How many times can a user change his, or her, profile name? I have just done it once, but want to know how many times I can do it again

Is there is a specific limit on changing a profile name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no limit. You can change your profile name as many times as you want. But keep in mind that once you change your profile name, you have to wait 30 days to change it again.

The change name history you can see below your "helpful flag" count as recent name. The recent names is available for [next 90 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116960/152859).

Advice: Stack Overflow is a Q/A site not a Social Networking site, so you better not change your profile name frequently.

Comment: ok is there are any pros and cons then in making it change

Comment: There's a workaround though, I think it's still active. If you change your name on SO but not MSO you can use the button on MSO "set all accounts to use this info" or similar which over-rides all profiles settings on all linked sites.

Comment: ok thats nice @tombull89 and I understood Lucifer it but User has its privileges to do so within a particular time limit,thanks any more things related with profile changes

Comment: If you want more information you can look at the questions tagged [meta-tag:usernames] @NetStarter or maybe [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) can help?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards thanks it really helped the Rate Limiting guide,appreciate your feedback thanks to all..:)