# What is "recent names" in my profile page?

Tags: discussion, questions, profile-page, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who can see the “past names” field in user profiles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116793/who-can-see-the-past-names-field-in-user-profiles)

In my [profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/172214/kjuly), there's a `recent names` under `profile views`. And I clicked the `number`(mine is `2`), it shown as below:

[image]

What is it? And what the `display name`? I haven't seen it before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The popup shows the changes to your user name (currently Kjuly).

From the dates, it appears to have been an `Anonymous` account that then got a GUID followed by your current user name. Possibly this is from an automated migration from another account.

See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116801/make-the-past-names-list-public-info-for-30-days-after-changing-your-name) and links from it.

Comment: But I have not changed my user name before. :?

Comment: @Kjuly - As I said, this may be a result of an automated migration.

Comment: By the system? Mum..weird..

Comment: BTW, can you see it in my profile page? not the image I shown.

Comment: @Kjuly:  No, only you and moderators can see your recent names.

Comment: @TimCooper I see, thank you. :)

Comment: The odd GUID-like account might have been caused by linking accounts; see [Linking / creating account on other sites adds 2 “recent names” to your profile?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118256/linking-creating-account-on-other-sites-adds-2-recent-names-to-your-profile), @Kjuly.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what the recent names in your case means:

- When you first visited this site you were an Anonymous user.
- Then you tried to log-in into the site and the 2nd string is probably the unique identifier from the service you are registering/loggin in with.
- After these steps you got your current username.

Hence, you have got 2 other display names in the recent names list.

Comment: Ya, I think so, but I wonder why it didn't show until yesterday. Anyway, thank you for your reply. :D