# Can we get more opportunities to "earn" Stack Overflow swag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, t-shirt, events, swag

In light of the Stack Exchange swag store closing (luckily I already got my SO shirt), I've realized it's very difficult to get a Stack Overflow t-shirt. I propose we get more opportunities across all Stack Exchange sites, but especially Stack Overflow. Super User had a big swag opportunity with the Windows 8 release, but I don't recall Stack Overflow ever having such a thing. The only thing I know of as a sure way to get a T-Shirt is to get 100k reputation, which for many people would take decades of work. Why not offer a few more opportunities to those people who haven't dedicated their lives to SO?

Some initial ideas:

1. Offer swag in contests/events. Why was no swag involved in participation of the [windows-8](/questions/tagged/windows-8) tag during the [apptivate](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/09/apptivate-ms-a-windows-8-app-development-contest/) event!?*
2. Have "lotteries" around the yearly surveys, like "everyone gets a sticker, 100 lucky participants get a shirt"
3. Rewards on getting really hard/rare badges (ledgendary, populist, etc)
4. Some kind of weekly or monthly challenge type system like "top user in the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag for this week gets a shirt"

* To be fair, Apptivate did have a chance for some swag, but it required a 10+ voted post on the [windows-8](/questions/tagged/windows-8) just for a chance to win 1 out of just 50 T-Shirts that were Apptivate shirts, not Stack Overflow shirts.

Comment: I never got [my t-shirt](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118256/linking-creating-account-on-other-sites-adds-2-recent-names-to-your-profile#comment311975_118649). :(

Comment: If there was a contest to get an official SO t-shirt with [Bobince's legendary answer to parsing XHTML with Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/334849) on it, I'm 99% sure I would do shameful things for that.

Comment: The cake is a lie.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables just realized that answer may not be around forever, currently locked over "content dispute?" and if you look in the history, it's been locked and unlocked by different diamond mods probably 15 times

Comment: @Earlz: It was locked because people kept editing out pretty much the entire post, and remains locked to prevent that from happening. I'm not sure what reasons the mods had for the continual unlock/lock actions, but the re-lockings have occurred almost immediately after the unlockings. I assure you the answer is not going anywhere, though.

Comment: @animuson That's because [it wasn't all that rare](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118256/linking-creating-account-on-other-sites-adds-2-recent-names-to-your-profile#comment312291_118649) ;)

Comment: I bought the T-shirt and mug before the store closed :P

Comment: @Earlz That is *the most* famous answer on Stack Overflow. It is referenced more times than any other, and it is almost instantly linked to on any question asking to parse HTML with regex. There is no doubt that the answer will live on forever.