# Consider not include default user##### name in the list of recent names if it was changed quickly

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, display-names

I scanned many threads related to "recent names" list but did not find anything similar. The clue is: consider not to include that default system-given `user#######` name to the list of recent names at all, **if user changes it *immediately* after account creation**.

Sure thing "immediately" is not a precise thing in the context, but there are several possible conditions for the definition (at least several examples that came at a glance):

1. Until the 1st post (answer or question)
2. Until the 1st profile view
3. If a user changes their name within 5-10-24 hours of account creation (exact timeframe to be discussed) and the above 2 points are not [yet] applicable.

The reasons:

- As soon as I created my account on SO, I filled in the bio and changed my display name - in a matter of minutes. However, I still have that "recent names" string in my profile which lists the only record so far - that default `user########` name. *Technically* - yes, I had it indeed. But *practically* - I don't think so!.. Hardly ever it was seen by anyone else. Still, it's a whole ROW on my profile page, which is still here at least for 90 days... (if even be removed thereafter).
- I know this is visible for me, devs and modders, but even for the last it may be more *confusing* than helpful: the list has `1`, but that name was never ***practically*** seen.

I know there are many folks who still have that default name (even with several K of rep) - that's their choice. But in that case they **don't** have that extra row displayed in their profile, while I do - and that's really annoying, since my display is not so huge.

I don't mind having this for 90 days if I change my name in the future - it's a fair cost for doing that, but it should be displayed only if required - e.g. as `helpful flags` counter.

Perhaps many people do not even care about such nuances, but being QA with almost 5 years of experience made me catch these things.

Comment: _"Perhaps many people do not even care about such nuances..."_ people definitely care about the small things, just read a few meta posts... :-)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I do agree, but the emphasis should be **MANY** - that's more accurate here)

Comment: Not nearly as annoying as [other automated names that previously got added](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118256/linking-creating-account-on-other-sites-adds-2-recent-names-to-your-profile).

Comment: @animuson That's a bit different: I don't want to see that string for the 1st 90 days at all.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see the need for additional complications in the system just to appease you for a whole 90 days. Technically, yes you did you use the name, for however short of a period of time.

- Your criteria, well, don't really achieve anything.  As you've stated, normal users cannot even see it - only you and moderators. So whether or not it shows up for you when you've participated yet or not doesn't really change anything, as other users wouldn't be able to tell that you changed your name unless they *know* your username was different previously.
- It's not an *entire* row, it's *just* a row. We're not penalizing you for changing your name, it's just information there for you to look at. If you really think it's *that* annoying, a better feature request would be to just hide it sooner. The only real use it has to the user is seeing how many days you have to wait until you can change it again, but that use expires after 30 days, not 90. Even then, attempting to change your name will tell you *when* you can change your name.
- That user string never gets added when you create new accounts on other sites and link them. Your account gets automatically pre-filled with your existing username. So, it's not like this will happen to you everywhere you go, just the once. I think you will survive.

So, to conclude, criteria are useless. If people are really annoyed with it, it should be removed, not made overly complicated. But I don't think many people get annoyed with it at all.

Comment: So it appears that I'm punished for 90 days only for changing my default username, while others who accepted it - have no such field and no extra rows in bio part. Moreover, imagine you apply the proposal - hardly ever anyone will complain. If not - still there are people like me who notice such details, such as @benisuǝqbackwards in comments to the question.

Comment: So...... As soon as this is the only answer - is it possible to officially mark the question with `bydesign` tag so that I could "solve" it?