# Mr. UUID guy just entered our chatroom

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat

So, this guy enters the JavaScript chat room:

[image]

However, when I look at his chat profile - I see this:

[image]

His main profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3161072/user3161072
See the chat profile: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/3161072/a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae

Comment: A unique experience?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know what that's about; I refreshed his chat profile and his name changed to the one he uses on the main site.

Comment: When you say "refreshed" do you mean from some sort of admin console you have or as in refreshed your browser?

Comment: Also, should this be closed as [meta-tag:status-completed] or are you figuring out why that happened in the first place?

Comment: I don't know what caused it and can't really dig into it at the moment, so I'm leaving this open in case someone else encounters the same problem. And yeah, there's an admin UI in chat that pulls fresh user information from the API.

Comment: Look who popped in for another visit http://imgur.com/DkEcojk

Answer (score 7):

I just stumbled across some of these users as well (there's [125 of them on SO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/249500/uuid-usernames), [3 on SU](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/249500/uuid-usernames), and [3 on MSE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/249500/uuid-usernames) at the time of this writing; I did not check other sites). Apparently they are leftovers from some dummy default username created for new accounts. [There are more details in this answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118649/230261) From there, Marc Gravell writes:

> ... apparently ... new accounts start with a dummy name, that is filled in ASAP ...
>
> ```
> // some random string so obnoxious people will complain about it
> public const string NewUserDisplayName = "a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae";
> ```