# Profile Page: toggle 'more/less info' will render the 'recent names' wrong

Tags: bug, profile-page, design

When I go to my profile page I see this :

[image]

After selecting the surrounding text I see that it is the 'recent names' field that is being renedered wrong.

Browser: Google Chrome Versie 22.0.1229.79 m

Comment: What's "recent names"?. I don't have this, neither well nor badly rendered... EDIT : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117065/what-is-recent-names-in-my-profile-page