# How can I see history of my display names?

Tags: support, profile-page, display-names

[Keep short history of user display names - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28924/keep-short-history-of-user-display-names)

> Add a tab in the Profile for 'Name History'.

Where is this? Can someone screenshot this? Thanks!

Comment: Apparently this never made it into the GUI: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101859/186472

Comment: Well, if you are after a particular name, you could find out what the ancestors were using web-archive, for instance (not guaranteed, but that should work)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't, [unless you're a ♦ moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116793/295232):

[image: Screenshot of User History in the moderator tools, with the filter "Edit DisplayName" applied. Two events are displayed, with the date and the username changed detailed (from user5 to user4)]